# Spring boot MockMvc returning wrong status code

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

I am testing an `@RestController` which has an API endpoint such as `/api/dataobject`. If the object (in JSON format) that is posted to this endpoint is missing some part of its meta data, the API should respond with a Http status of bad request (400).

When testing it through Postman, this works, however in my unit test where the controller is mocked it still returns a status 200.

The method in the `RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/dataobject")
    public ResponseEntity postDataObject(@RequestBody final DataObject dataObject) throws InvalidObjectException {
        if (!dataObjectValidator.validateDataObject(dataObject)) {
            throw new InvalidObjectException("Data object was invalid: " + dataObject.toString());
        }

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The `InvalidObjectException` is caught by a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` which extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and is handled as follows:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = InvalidObjectException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidObject(final InvalidObjectException exception, final WebRequest request) {
        final String bodyOfResponse = exception.getMessage();

        return handleExceptionInternal(exception, bodyOfResponse, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
```

Now, the unit test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DataObjectController.class)
public class DataObjectControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private DataObjectController dataObjectController;

    private final String uri = "/api/idataobject";

    @Test
    public void noAppName() throws Exception {
        DataObject object = getDataObjectNoAppName();

        final String body = new Gson().toJson(object);

        given(dataObjectController.postDataObject(object)).willReturn(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));

        mvc.perform(post(uri)
                .content(body)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

Even though the object is invalid, and I've said that the given object would return a HttpStatus 400, I get a 200 status in return.

Clearly I'm missing something here, but what?

Comment: Are you sure you want to mock DataObjectController (I would assume this is controller under test, isn't it)?

Comment: Oh no, my bad, that indeed was the problem. I knew it had to be something obvious, thank you!